# User focus in multitouch environment

Tags: wpf, multi-touch

I am trying to create a multitouch application.
I have the hardware which will allow me to do this. On the software side I want to be able to have WPF textboxes, WPF web browsers, multiple focuses, multiple keyboards and multiple users at the same time.

From what I've seen, I can't be focused on two controls at the same time.

What is the Microsoft MultiTouch approach for this kind of job ?

Comment: When you say multi-touch you mean multi-user in most cases, don't you? Or rather, that is the key problem here, that touch is used as input seems secondary to me.

Comment: AFAIK windows only supports one user focus. non-touch equivalent would be plugging in 2 keyboards. If you want, for example, a keyboard on each side of a touchscreen each typing into their respective interfaces you'll probably have to implement your own keyboard into the app  (you could probably find one to re-use) and have it work whether the app had focus or not. Of course each keyboard and app instance would have to have their own screen space. Windows would be swapping the focus as both users typed; you'd have to ignore it and manage it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The OS limitations are what they are (and don't appear to change in Win8): only one hWnd at a time can have focus.

Since you are using WPF though, everything within your application (with the exception of the WebBrowser control ActiveX widgets you may be using) is rendered within one big hWnd.

WPF 4 introduced native support for multitouch, including multi-touch capture.  The APIs for this are many but pretty intuitive so I'll just say this... go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590078.aspx and search within the page for all of the members with "Touch" in their name.

The catch however is that the controls shipping with WPF 4 *don't* work with the touch input events... you'll only be able to interact with one of those controls at a time.  To take advantage of the multi-touch capture APIs, you'll have to create controls that are designed with it in mind.  Fortunately, the Surface team at Microsoft has you covered on that... the "Surface 2.0 SDK" includes a suite of controls (usable on any Win7 machine, not just for Surface) that were built with this stuff in mind.

Answer (score 0):

To create application with MultiTouch UI, use MultiTouch Framework in .Net

Go to http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/